# Can't showing up as Can\'t

Tags: php

How can I fix contractions in php so they do not show up with the backslash? It is showing up with the slash in my iOS and android applications, so I have checked the backend but I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Give us some piece of your code in order to help you.

Comment: You need to trace through your code and figure out where they are being added. (And that's a backslash not a forward slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have `magic_quotes` enabled to your server. That mean's if you `$_POST` some data, it auto*magic*ally adds quotes to your `$_POST` data. (It sucks, i know, that's why it's **[deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)** by now). That means if your data is going into your database from a `php` `$_POST` that's the source of the problem.

Turn off that thing **http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php** and then clear your already "magic-quoted" data in your MYSQL database by doing a `REPLACE`

`UPDATE your_content_table SET your_content_column = REPLACE(your_content_column, '\\\'', '\'');`

This way, your problems will go away and never happen again.

Data that resides in database must be in pure form, without any escaping. The escaping prior to display is not something for the database to do, its a display problem and you need to handle that wherever you display something.

If the above is not the case, then just perform `stripslashes($yourstring)` to get a string without that backslash. But this is just a bandaid, you need to fix the problem at its source.

Comment: Okay, I did not have a php.ini file. Does this mean the link will not solve my problem, or should I create a php.ini then turn off magic quotes?

Comment: @KellyWatson you sure have a php.ini file maybe you mean you can't access it? you can try adding in your `.htaccess` file this line `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off`. oh, and check this out may help you find your `php.ini` http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's function stripslashes:

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

**EDIT**

As per @Quentin's comment below, better if the slashes weren't added in the first place.

Comment: Better to stop them being added in the first place.

Comment: Slashes are sometimes added for a reason 
see: http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to add slashes (although almost never with the addslashes function, more specific escaping functions should be used in almost every case) … but if they are showing out in the output, then they shouldn't be added to that data.